# I feel like the server cannot find my file even though the file path is correct

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

My plan is to check all textfields whether they are empty or not. If empty I want to display an error message and keep displaying the SignUp.jsp. This is the code:

```
if (uEmail.isEmpty() || uFName.isEmpty() || uLName.isEmpty() || uPass.isEmpty()) {
    request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "All fields are required!");
    dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/SignUp.jsp");
}
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

But the problem is I feel like the server cannot find my file even though the file path is correct.

This is my file path:
[image]

My expectation is for the servlet to keep displaying the sign up page (SignUp.jsp) whenever any block code is executed.

Btw, I have already tried changing the file path to

```
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user/SignUp.jsp");
```

or

```
dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("SignUp.jsp");
```

But still didn't work.

Comment: What about `dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user/SignUp.jsp");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path from the web app root folder will be

```
/user/SignUp.jsp
```

So you can use this code to forward to the JSP

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/SignUp.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The problem is in your code where you get a dispatcher in the `if` block and if the condition is `false` then a dispatcher won't get a path to the JSP.

Comment: Thank you it works. Btw, I have another dispatcher at the top outside if block, the code above is just a partial code. Thanks

Comment: There's no need to keep a dispatcher outside if block because it'is used only once.